# Eclipse doesn't recognize my Android phone (HTC Sensation)

Tags: android, eclipse, windows-8

I've got **Windows 8** and I've get Eclipse installed. I tried to run an application on my phone, **HTC Sensation**, but Eclipse doesn't find it. When I press the run button, it says: "No compatible targets were found. Do you wish to a add new android virtual device?" But when I connect Samsung Galaxy S3 to computer, it magically works! But sadly, that is not my phone. It must work on Sensation. Oh, and on Windows 7, it was working perfectly.

As far.. I tried a lot of thing, but nothing worked.

- I tried to install the newest HTC Sync, doesn't work.
- I tried to reboot my phone, ADB and Eclipse, but doesn't work.
- I tried to run HTC Sync (HTC Sync doesn't recognize Sensation too) in compatibility mode in Windows 7, and I tried to run it as administrator, but it doesn't work.
- I searched the web, but nothing helps...
- In device Maneger, under "Other Devices" it is "Android phone", but there is yellow triangle, and anything I click... nothing helps.

Also, I can browse and copy files to SD card on my phone. So Windows DOES recognize my phone!
*But before, when i had Windows 7, everything works perfectly!*

Comment: Seems like the debugging is just not working for your phone on Win8. You should watch for updated adb drivers

Comment: Yes, debugging is turned on and sadly, it doesn't work yet.

Comment: What does "adb devices" return?

Comment: Other things to try would be adding the device id to adb_usb.ini, and checking permissions. Also, figure out what the yellow triangle is trying to tell you. It probably matters

Comment: adb devices hasn't return nothing. But now, I repair it and it works. I found some kind of driver, which was unsigned,and I had to install it. (I had to allow unsigned drivers to be installed). And now it Work! But thank you guys anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things you can try:

- Install [USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) to unregister the drivers and install them again
- Use another USB port/cable. Some people have problems with the front ports of the pc, or with USB3 ports. Also, a low quality cable can cause your phone to connect and disconnect over and over again.

Comment: Um, did something change? Why is this the answer if it didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the google drivers, and update to them in the Control Panel.

Comment: I've got google driver installed... But what do you mean by "update to them in the control panel"? Where exactly, I don't see them in Control panel --> programs.

Comment: Control Panel -> System -> Device Manager -> Find the phone -> Update Driver -> From a location, choose location